# Sparx Enterprise Architect Find Operations Used by

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have defined a class with operations, and the operations are used in several sequence diagrams.

Is there a way I can find out how many sequence diagrams are using one particular operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you should be able to do the following:

1. Expand your class in the 'Project Browser' to see operations
2. Right click on the operation and choose "Find in all diagrams..."
   from context menu

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't have the context menu item of "Find in all diagrams". Which version of EA are you running? I am still on 8.3, wait for my company to upgrade me.

Comment: I am using 9.0. I think this feature was there for a while though. In my case I created operation first, and then I used it in sequence diagram. Not sure if that matters.

Comment: The name of the command may have changed, but the shortcut will be the same: Ctrl+U

Comment: I am using 15.0 and I cannot do that for operations. When I do a Ctlr + U, it looks for the usage of the class, not the function itself

Answer (score 1):

I can't remember now if EA 8 included the facility to create project browser scripts, ie ones that can be called via a right-click in the project browser. This is available in EA 9 and EA 10.

If it's there in EA 8, you can create such a script to perform the lookup. Offhand, you'd need to look in the tables t_operation, t_connectortag and t_connector to find the references.